# How to integrate push notifications in react native while using react native navigation

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, react-native

Can someone help me to add push notification service in my react native app? As I am using react-native-navigation library in my app I am unable to use any other push notification library rather than react-native-notifications but the documentation is not quite good I have performed the installation and setup part completely and as the result, I am getting the message from the firebase in the notification but after that stage I am unable to understand the Subscription  and other parts of the documentation for manually handling the message in the app. Please let me know if someone can help!!!

Comment: try this https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Comment: @Lucefer I think I have mentioned in my question that react native push notifications does not work correctly with react native navigation.

Comment: is it not work due to react-native-navigation ??

Comment: @Lucefer It will work but not correctly some the functionalities will not work properly right now I am working on a solution for this. If that works I will post it here.